# Sql cartesian product (summing with group by)

Tags: sql, group-by, sas, query-optimization, cartesian-product

I am trying to calculate the sum of volume for the last thirty days for a set of stocks on particular days in the table `important_stock_dates`. The table `all_stock_dates` contains the same stocks but with trading volume for all dates, not just the particular days.

**Sample data**

all_stock_dates

```
stockid, date, volume  
0231245, 20060314, 153  
0231245, 20060315, 154  
2135411, 20060314, 23
```

important_stock_dates

```
stockid, date, thirtydaysprior  
0231245, 20060314, 20060130  
0231245, 20060315, 20060201  
2135411, 20060314, 20060130
```

**My code**

```
create table sum_trading_volume as
select a.stockid, a.date, sum(b.volume) as thirty_day_volume
from important_stock_dates a, all_stock_dates b
where b.date<a.date AND b.date ge a.thirtydaysprior
group by a.stockid, a.date;
```

**Desired outcome**

A table with all the observations from `important_stock_dates` that also has the sum of the volume from the previous 30 days based on matching stockid and dates in `all_stock_dates`.

**Problem**

The problem I'm running into is that `important_stock_dates` has 15 million observations and `all_stock_dates` has 350 million. It uses up a few hundred gigabytes of swap file running this code (maxes out the hard drive) then aborts. I can't see how to optimize the code. I couldn't find a similar problem on StackOverflow or Google.

Comment: (1) Provide sample data and desired results.  (2) Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: It's not a cartesian product, because there actually is a join condition buried in the `WHERE` clause, q.v. the comment by @jarlh above.

Comment: You join an `important_stock_dates` with all `all_stock_dates` records which date is between `thirtydaysprior` and `date`. How many `all_stock_dates` records match this condition usually for an `important_stock_dates` record? 1? 20? 30? Or 100,000? You are multiplying your 15 million observations by this number before applying the aggregation (the summing of `volume`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably, the query that you want joins on `stockid`:

```
create table sum_trading_volume as
    select isd.stockid, isd.date, sum(asd.volume) as thirty_day_volume
    from important_stock_dates isd join
         all_stock_dates asd
         on isd.stockid = asd.stockid and
            asd.date < isd.date and asd.date >= isd.thirtydaysprior
    group by isd.stockid, isd.date;
```

If this worked, it will probably run to completion.

Comment: Good thinking. Also very nice to see appropriate alias names and proper joins :-)

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly and very quickly (about 6 minutes). I'm trying to understand what you've written so I don't make the same mistake again. Any idea why your code works and mine doesn't?

Comment: @user6050 . . . Learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Although you could get the query to work with `WHERE`, you are more likely to write correct queries if you use appropriate syntax.